# Unable to delete the first Google Team Drive I created

Tags: google-drive, google-shared-drive

I am brand new to Team Drives.  I created a few test team drives, but the first one, for some reason, is different than the others.  It's icon has a key symbol on it (see photo).

The original name I gave it was replaced by "Team Drive".  Ever since then, however, when I create a new team drive, it accepts the name I give it (e.g., "Test", "Untitled Team Drive 2", etc.).

I have the option to delete the other ones, but not the first one I created, the one named "Team Drive".  Why is this first team drive different -- and, how is it different?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually the issue corrected itself.  I had just created the Team Drive, and needed to wait long enough for it to fully establish itself.

Answer (score 2):

The icon on the Google Drive left panel for the Team Drive unit named "Team Drive" shows a key. That could means that it doesn't belong the organization of the account being used to access Google Drive or that that the administrator has not allowed users to create Team Drives.

In order to be able to delete that unit

- The unit should be empty
- The user should be using an account with Full Access that belongs to the same organization that the Team Drive unit belongs to.

Answer (score -3):

just remove yourself as a member